# How to make a `do while` loop (its stop condition) depend on the callback of an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, do-while

Consider the following code:

```
var x = 0;
do {
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: someurl,
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: xmlString, 
    success: function(xml) { 
             x++;
    }

} while(x<10);
```

This would, of course, not work because thousands requests would be made to "someurl", so how would I go about changing this code in order to have the `do while` condition depend on the callback of the asynchronous HTTP request?
In other words, how would I have the do-while loop continue only upon calling the request callback? So that only 11 iterations will be made, not thousands.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the usage where you're applying this?

Comment: Well, I have a function that makes such an asynchronous request to a server that holds a database and its callback changes the value of a variable. And the request needs to repeat itself until that variable reaches a certain value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could re-write it like this:

```
var x = 0;

function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: someurl,
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: xmlString, 
    success: function(xml) { 
        x++;
        if (x<10) ajaxCall();
        else afterAjaxCall();
    }
}

function afterAjaxCall() {}
```

This way, the method calls itself when it succeeds ten times, then calls the 'after' method to continue with your other code.

Answer (score 4):

```
var x = 0;
function callAjax() {
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: someurl, 
        dataType: 'xml', 
        data: xmlString,  
        success: function(xml) {
            x++;
            if(x < 10){                     
                callAjax();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea with this is that the `success` method first increments the counter, then checks it against the maximum number of calls. If it is less, another `ajaxCall` is made. Making the additional calls in the `success` method is the only way to prevent massive numbers of calls being made (`$ajax` is of course asynchronous and thus returns immediately)

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = 0;
function A() {
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: someurl,
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: xmlString, 
    success: function(xml) { 
            x++;
            if(x<10)
            A();
    }

}
A();
```

Comment: Code only or link only answers are not encouraged, you should add some explanatory text to your answer.

Comment: @slugster Nevertheless, it's quite understandable to me :)

Comment: @AndreiOniga That's not what counts - how understandable is it to everyone else? You've given an answer but not added value - how is your answer better than the others? You need to elaborate. (Note that your answer popped up in the low quality review queue, hence my comment).

Comment: I think the code is self-explanatory, unnecessary comments and explanations are worse than nothing at all if the code is understandable.

Comment: I agree with elclanrs. By the way, I posted the question, not the answer, slugster. :))

Comment: @AndreiOniga So you did. I stand by my comment though (and I'm not going to continue arguing it). These answers appear in the low quality review queue because they are code only, which is not encouraged. End of story. Hopefullly Man and the other answerers will put some explanation so that other budding javascript programmers can understand the difference between them and why one is chosen as the answer (or more upvoted) than the other.